# save mongo entity to the different collections

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've been using Spring Data for saving entities to the mongo DB and my code at the moment looks like this:

I have a repo class:

```
public interface LogRepo extends MongoRepository<Log, String> {

}
```

and I have an Entity Log which looks like this:

```
@Document(
        collection = "logs"
)
public class Log {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String jsonMessage;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJsonMessage() {
        return jsonMessage;
    }

    public void setJsonMessage(String jsonMessage) {
        this.jsonMessage = jsonMessage;
    }
}
```

and this work well for me, however this approach works only for the case if I want to save Log entities to "logs" collection. However it would be very nice for me to be able to save Log entity to different collections depending on the context. I mean it would be nice to define collection name in the runtime. Is it possible somehow?

Thanks, cheers

Comment: I guess defining collection at runtime is still not available, I too had the  same problem. I had to use Custom Implementation for MongoRepository

Comment: @user3632894 I've been looking for a way to handle this for a couple of days and found nothing. Seems like custom implementation is the only way for a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use inheritance and define appropriate collection names in such way. May give you possibility to save in different collections but you will be still not able to specify dynamically collection names and resp. their amount at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems like the only way to handle situation is to write a custom implementation

Answer (score 1):

```
@Document(
        collection = "logs"
)
public class Log {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String jsonMessage;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJsonMessage() {
        return jsonMessage;
    }

    public void setJsonMessage(String jsonMessage) {
        this.jsonMessage = jsonMessage;
    }
}

@Document(
        collection = "log_child"
)
public class LogChild extends Log{}
```

With the MongoOperations save method you can choose which class to use and 
based on the class it will choose the appropriate collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Document(collection = "collection_#{T(com.github.your_project.DBUtils).getCollectionName()}")
public Class Collection
```

You can change the name in real time using a static getter

```
@UtilityClass
public class DBUtils {

    private String collectionName;

    public String getCollectionName() {
        return collectionName;
    }

    public void setCollectionName(String collectionName) {
        DBUtils.collectionName = collectionName;
    }
}
```