# Can the @Document annotation in SpringData be overridden if the parent class also has it?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a microservice that is trying to query from two different collections. Both contain the exact same objects types, except there is a `status` field that can have a value of `"Archived"\Discarded"`. These objects are stored in the `archived_collection` as opposed to ones that have `status: "Published/Unmapped"`

So my question is, is it possible that the collection for the parent class be used if i extend the child class from it and they both have different values for `@Document()`?

Here's what the code would look like.

`Class 1`:

```
@Document("original_collection")
public class parentObject{
//some fields
}
```

`Class 2`:

```
@Document("archived_collection")
public class archivedObject extends parentObject{
//no extra fields. exact same as parentObject
}
```

Mind you, there's only one `MongoTemplate` object in the code since both these collections are in the same database. So currently, my application seems to not be searching in the archived collection at all and just goes straight to the original collection. My guess is what i've described in the question title. If that is the case, I would appreciate some help working around this.

Comment: In relational Spring Data you can change the inheritance type of the class, so the tables are created separately or there's only the parent table with all the columns/fields, to me it looks the same case, try to find a inheritance configuration, so you can change how the documents are created there.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113372/9391162

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: The issue posed in the question does not stem from the suggestion i gave. Spring Data will accurately retrieve from the proper collection even if the inheritance is as given above. The issue is somewhere in my project's logic after adding a new feature.

So if anybody stumbles upon this, thinking they have a similar issue; it's probably your logic somewhere else.